# team foundation server 2010 admin console issue

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

when I go to application tier, configure installed features ,start wizard,
it will ask whether I would like to have sharepoint on this machine or not, I go for it and the error displays is:

```
TF400081: Cannot connect to the Internet. An Internet connection is needed to be able to install SharePoint.
```

We are using a proxy on the network to access the internet, when I look in the log it says:

```
Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. (type WebException)Status: ProtocolError
Response Status Code: ProxyAuthenticationRequired
```

how can I run the standard configuration wizard do that it gets authenticated by the proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because it's trying to download all the prerequisites for sharepoint.  It may just be easier to do an offline install by manually installing the prereqs yourself.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/patrick_heyde/archive/2010/03/02/install-sharepoint-2010-without-internet-access.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways:
1. switch off require authentication for your server on proxy

1. install your own intermediate proxy (Proxomitron.info for example) on you work computer and make TFS server to connect to you proxy instead of corporate.
   And configure an intermediate proxy to bypass all connection without authentication.